# Need to find border co-ordinates and near by cities, villages and towns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am looking to plot the boundary region of current user and nearby villages and cities border. I am using ruby on rails.

For that I have downloaded a kml file from the [site](http://www.gadm.org/download) having the co-ordinate informations of all cities in japan. I have parsed the kml file and inserted it into database.

To find nearby cities I have used the logic 'Two boundary cities have same co-ordinate point'. But when I queried to find the nearby cities of a city I couldn't get all the nearby cities as in google.

So please suggest me a better way to do this.

Comment: are you using any library for this purpose..adding more details and code snippets would be helpful

Comment: To parse the file I am using java and library using is javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser. I am storing the coordinates in database and to find nearby cities I am checking for cities with any of the coordinate of the city. Is there any library in rails

Comment: I am pretty sure this library https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder would solve your issue. you can pass co-ordinates and radius range to find all cities, village near by. Also, I would highly recommend watching this video by Rayan bates : http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?autoplay=true